# Write a Bash script which will take a single command line argument (a directory) and will print each entry in that directory

Tags: bash, directory

Issue : Folders are treated as Files

My Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for var in $(ls)
do
    echo $var
    if [ -e $var ]
    then
        echo "This is a file"
    else
        echo "This is not a file"
    fi
done

echo All Done
```

Current Contents of the Root Folder:

`-rw-r--r--  1 stibo stibo    401 Sep 17  2015 id_rsa.pub
drwxrwxr-x 24 stibo stibo   4096 Jul 26 09:25 step
-rwxr-xr-x  1 stibo stibo     51 Jul 27 12:51 test.txt
drwxrwxrwx  2 stibo stibo   4096 Aug  2 10:32 deletionFile
-rwxrw-r--  1 stibo stibo    225 Aug  2 12:32 deletionScript.vi
-rw-rw-r--  1 stibo stibo    235 Aug  2 12:33 logdetails.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 stibo stibo    123 Aug  2 12:42 path1.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 stibo stibo    285 Aug  2 16:18 path2.txt
drwxrwxr-x  2 stibo stibo   4096 Aug  3 10:14 archival
-rw-rw-r--  1 stibo stibo      0 Aug  3 13:42 ls
-rw-rw-r--  1 stibo stibo 164732 Aug  3 14:11 messages
-rw-rw-r--  1 stibo stibo 164732 Aug  3 14:11 wtmp
drwxrwxrwx  2 stibo stibo   4096 Aug  3 14:21 backup
-rwxrwxr-x  1 stibo stibo    160 Aug  4 15:34 newScript.vi
-rw-rw-r--  1 stibo stibo    160 Aug  4 15:41 Code.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 stibo stibo      0 Aug  4 15:43 Details.txt`

Where there are **4 folders** and **12 files**.

But when I run the script, I could see every thing is considered as a file, even if there are folders in it.

Can you please let me know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You've tested if a given entry exists with -e. Use -d for testing for directories and -f for files

Comment: And please use `for file in *` instead of `$(ls)`. For example, `touch 'some file` and watch for the error relating to "file"

Comment: Yes, this is working if I keep the option as -f for file. Also I used for file in *. Why is this suggested instead of $(ls) ?

Comment: You are reading each word in the output of ls into your loop. If the directory/file contains spaces, you won't get the space spearated entry but two separate entries. If you have to use $(ls), use "$(ls)" as this (to a certain extent) will deal with spaces in entries

Comment: The output of "$(ls)" :
00003_Up&Down 2_20130305_M001a.jpg1172075980953685840

Comment: The output of "$(ls)" :
00003_Up&Down 2_20130305_M001a.jpg1172075980953685840
IT_wrong_content loaded_3rd_July.txt

In Code for looping , I gave as :

for input in "$(ls)"

But still, the input is taken as following :
00003_Up&Down
2_20130305_M001a.jpg1172075980953685840
IT_wrong_content
loaded_3rd_July.txt

So basically the spaces are considered, Can you please suggest how can the spaces be overlooked and input is considered as the whole "$(ls)"